# UIButton with title and image

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I need a button with an image inside of it and a text under the button. I can't use the image as a background because it would stretch the image. So my problem is if I use an image for the button, the title will be covered by the image. Is there any solution for this?

Here is an example how it should look like at the end:

[image]

Comment: Yes you can achieve this by adjusting the title and image insets.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

1) Create UIView add Image , label and button

2)  You can to set Title And Image inset , You can do it in XIB   easily

For option two  I have added simple example , (Replace it with your value)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change Title and Image Insets

[image]

also change control Vertical to bottom

[image]

Comment: it doesn't worked for me... the title is still covered

Answer (score 0):

You could make a separate UIImage and UILabel at the positions you prefer, and cover them with transparent UIButton.
That should do the trick.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UIButton and redefine **layoutSubviews** method.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the following properties of `UIButton`: `var titleEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets`, `var imageEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets`.

Another way of doing this is subclassing `UIControl`. It's a `UIView` subclass that is meant to be used for such cases. `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIControl` for example. That way you have more control over the layout and you don't need to fight `UIButton`'s builtin behaviour.

You can do your layout either in code or with Interface Builder in a `xib` file.

```
class MyButton: UIControl {

    var imageView: UIImageView
    var label: UILabel

    // adjust colors for changed states like highlighting, etc.
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet { 
            if isHighlighted {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.grey              
            } else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.white             
            }
        }
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool { didSet { ... } }    
    override var isEnabled: Bool { didSet { ... } }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(...))
        addSubView(imageView)
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(...))     
        addSubView(label)
        // TODO: add constraints for layout
    }
}
```